# how to include certain header files by default so that i don't have to type them in every programs

Tags: c++, c

how to include certain header files by default so that i don't have to type them in every programs:
In dev c++ and code::blocks

Comment: Dont forget to accept your favourite answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Make a global header file that in turn includes whatever files you need in every project, and then you only have to include that single file.

However I would recommend against it, unless all your different project are very similar. Different projects have different needs and also need different header files.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* issue a compiler directive in your project file or make script to do "per project" includes, but in general I would avoid that.

Source code should be as clear as possible to any reader just by its content. Whenever I have source code that dramatically changes its semantics, eg. by headers that are unknown to me, this can be quite confusing.

On top of that, if you "inject" those headers for certain compilation units that don't need them, that will negatively impact compile time.

As a substitution, what about introducing a `common.h/hpp` header that includes those certain header files? You can then include your common header in all files that need them *and* change this common set of headers for all depending files at once. It also opens the door to use [precompiled header files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header), which may be worth a look for you.

Answer (score 1):

From GCC documentation (AFAIK GCC is default compiler used by the development environment you are citing)

> -include file
>
> Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file. However, the first directory searched for
>   file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the directory
>   containing the main source file. If not found there, it is searched
>   for in the remainder of the #include "..." search chain as normal.
>
> If multiple -include options are given, the files are included in the order they appear on the command line.
>
> -imacros file
>
> Exactly like -include, except that any output produced by scanning file is thrown away. Macros it defines remain defined. This allows you
>   to acquire all the macros from a header without also processing its
>   declarations.
>
> All files specified by -imacros are processed before all files specified by -include.

But it is usually a bad idea to use these.

Answer (score 0):

Dev c++ works with MingW compiler, which is gcc compiler for Windows. Gcc supports precompiled headers, so you can try that. Precompiled headers are header files that you want compiled and added to every object file in a project. Try searching for that in Google for some information.

Code::blocks supports them too, when used with gcc, even better, so there it may even be easier.

Comment: Precompiled headers are not relevant here. The OP doesn't want to type the `#include` lines.

Answer (score 0):

If your editor of choice supports macros, make one that adds your preferred set of include files.  Once made, all you have to do is invoke your macro to save yourself the repetitive typing and you're golden.

Hope this helps.